# Increment per File

Tags: java, file, directory, increment

Below is some of my code.  I am going through a folder, pulling every image, and finding the RGB value of every pixel, and determining which ones are blue.  I am trying to only increment per file, but for some reason, it is continuing and adding every file's increment.

```
try {
                int width = image.getWidth();
                int height = image.getHeight();

                for(int k = 0; k < height; k++){

                    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){

                        Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, k));

                        int redVal = c.getRed();
                        int greenVal = c.getGreen();
                        int blueVal = c.getBlue();
                        //24 42 72

                        if ((redVal >= 0) && (redVal <= 80)) {
                            if ((greenVal >= 40) && (greenVal <= 105)) {
                                if ((blueVal >= 80) && (blueVal <= 135)) {
                                    count++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                System.out.print(count +" pixels are \"blue\", ");
```

Output:

```
23700 pixels are "blue"
27199 pixels are "blue"
38136 pixels are "blue"
40834 pixels are "blue"
41443 pixels are "blue"
50349 pixels are "blue"
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Where do you initialize `count` and/or do you reset it before each file?

Comment: Well you should probably reset `count` before starting to count...

Comment: Please provide a complete example of your code - what you posted is incomplete (e. g. `count` is not declared).

Comment: Just reset `count` to `0` after you print its value or before counting.

Comment: You should declare your variables in the tightest possible scope, so that you don't risk re-using the value from 'last time'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `count` to only represent the blue in a single file, then reset it's value to 0 before iterating over the pixels:

```
int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();
count = 0;
...
```